# iOS Silent notification with background download task and local notification

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm trying to download file after receiving silent notification. I use background download task (I expect that this download could take more than 30 seconds). Then I want to show local notification.

Am I allowed to download big files based on silent notification? Is there any limitation when to show local notifications after background download task?

(I run into some weird randomness so I would like to confirm that I'm the on right path)

Comment: You need to ensure you call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` before you start the download

Comment: Do I have to call it even when I use NSURLSession configured for background? (downloadTaskWithRequest) I thought that when I start background download task system will take care about the download.